# Achievement link goes to wrong site

Tags: bug, achievements-dialog

I have a strange situation where *one* of my achievement drop-down links for a Super User question are linking to Stack Overflow. This is what the drop-down shows:

[image: Screenshot showing a link to a Super User question for a +2 rep bump from an edit]

However, the link that should be going to [Super User post 1800321](https://superuser.com/a/1800332) instead points to [Stack Overflow post 1800321](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1800321) which doesn't seem to exist? Here's a screenshot of my browser's link preview:

[image: Screenshot showing that the link that should take me to Super User is actually going to take me to Stack Overflow]

This seems to be an isolated incident in my achievement drop-down, as other Super User links work fine, but I could be wrong. This is the only edit achievement entry in my drop-down, so I can't check if others are affected.

Comment: This was fixed today - see the answer to the duplicate.